# how to completely remove a theme?

Tags: magento2.4, custom-theme, uninstall-module

in magento 2.2 with php 7.1 i had a theme (infortis).
now i have to update to magento 2.4 and php 8.1 the theme is not compatible, it must be removed completely.
to install the theme you had to copy some files with FTP and then launch a "module enable" command.
I tried to remove the modules with composer but it returns the error that they are not installed with composer.

So I disabled the modules and then removed the files I had ftp uploaded.

But I think this solution is not good because there are traces left in the DB and magento is not good, it can't find classes!

(Class "Infortis\UltraMegamenu\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Grid\Columns" does not exist)

What procedure should I use to properly clean magento 2.2 before upgrade?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To uninstall a manually added theme:**

1.Navigate to the vendor directory where the theme was installed. This directory should be: `<installation dir>/app/design/frontend/<VendorName>.`

2.Remove the theme directory.

3.Remove the theme record from database. If you are using MySQL, run
the following command to do this:

```
 mysql -u <user> -p -e "delete from <dbname>.theme where theme_path ='<Vendor>/<theme>' AND area ='frontend' limit 1"
```

[Please click for reference & details](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/themes/uninstall/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, after I've removed the DB entries frontend start to working